# How can GA4 new vs established be (not set)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a GA4 exploration with a single dimension (**New vs Established**) and a single metric (**sessions**).

A small number of sessions have the 'New vs Established) dimension as '**(not set)**'

This is only a small number (around 0.5% of all sessions) so isn't going to significantly impact reporting, but I am intrigued as to how this happens.

Unlike other properties, this is a binary - you're either one thing or the other... so how can some sessions be neither?

I thought this might potentially be related to certain events, but it appears not. This is showing for a relatively similar share of events under session_start, page_view, and custom events.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created customised dimensions, then you need to wait 48 hours, have a look at this link please:
[Google Custom dimensions Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20custom%20dimension,-In%20Google%20Analytics&text=In%20the%20Properties%20column%2C%20click,unique%20name%20for%20the%20dimension.)